# change extension and move file, using vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have the following code, which changes the extension of a txt to doc, and then moves it (from d:\1 to d:\2). The extension changes successfully, but it does not move, and I get an error

> Cannot create a file when that file already exists.

Please suggest.

```
For Each filePath In Directory.GetFiles("D:\1", "*.txt")
    File.Move(filePath, Path.ChangeExtension(filePath, ".doc"))
Next
Dim filesToMove = From f In New DirectoryInfo("d:\1").EnumerateFiles("*.doc")
For Each f In filesToMove
    f.MoveTo("d:\2")
Next
```

Comment: The argument you supply when calling the `MoveTo` method should be the path (including the destination filename), not just the directory. Check the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.moveto(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Just get rid of `From f In` and put parentheses around `New DirectoryInfo("d:\1")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will check for an existing file of the same name and delete it first (you may want to handle this differently). It will then move and rename in one call to `File.Move`

```
Dim directory1 = "D:\1"
Dim directory2 = "D:\2"
For Each oldFileName In Directory.GetFiles(directory1, "*.txt")
    Dim newFileName = Path.ChangeExtension(oldFileName, ".doc").Replace(directory1, directory2)
    If File.Exists(newFileName) Then File.Delete(newFileName)
    File.Move(oldFileName, newFileName)
Next
```

Comment: The problem in the OP appears not to be that the file exists, but that the filename is omitted from the destination path (each file is being copied to "D:\2" instead of "D:\2\<SomeFileName>"

Comment: Great, then this solves his problem, and is a bit more robust.

Comment: This is a [minimal complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You may need to edit it to work in your specific case.

Answer (score 0):

ok, finally found the solution. not very professional, but works anyways: ( Many thanks to all members who have helped earlier)

```
Private Sub logchange(ByVal source As Object, 
                      ByVal e As System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs)
    If e.ChangeType = IO.WatcherChangeTypes.Changed Then

        Dim sourceDirectory As String = "D:\1"
        Dim archiveDirectory As String = "D:\2"
        Try
            Dim jpgFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(sourceDirectory, "*.wav")
            For Each currentFile As String In jpgFiles
                Dim fileName = Path.GetFileName(currentFile)
                Directory.Move(currentFile, Path.Combine(archiveDirectory, 
                    Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName) & ".doc"))
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
        End Try

    End If

    If e.ChangeType = IO.WatcherChangeTypes.Created Then

        Dim sourceDirectory As String = "D:\1"
        Dim archiveDirectory As String = "D:\2"
        Try
            Dim jpgFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(sourceDirectory, "*.wav")
            For Each currentFile As String In jpgFiles
                Dim fileName = Path.GetFileName(currentFile)
                Directory.Move(currentFile, Path.Combine(archiveDirectory, 
                    Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName) & ".doc"))
            Next
            Catch ex As Exception
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
        End Try

    End If

End Sub
```